# Firefox overflow hidden requires float

Tags: html, css, firefox, styles

I tested on Chrome, Opera, even Internet Explorer, my below css works as expected.

```
.carousel
{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.carousel-inner
{
    font-size:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:6882px;
}

.carousel-item
{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px 16px;
}
```

But when I tested on Firefox, `.carousel-inner` is not hiding overflowing element.

In order to add the same effect, I need to add `float:left` to `.carousel-inner`, which renders `width:100%` to be ignored.

Is there another work around specific to Firefox?

I tried `clear:both` with no luck.

Here is jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/samueladam/VKPku/3/)

And image (Chrome, IE, Opera) :

[image]

Firefox :

[image: firefox]

Cheers !

Comment: if you were running the same thing on firefox before doing these changes also, then try clearing your cache.. it happens with me, everything works fine in IE but sometimes not in firefox because it does not load the latest css sometimes

Comment: clearing cache is not working :)

Comment: well thats a big headache now !!
go through this , if it might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237419/weird-firefox-overflow-float-behavior?rq=1

Comment: still no good, tried to add clear both to each, and eventually every element, still no luck

Comment: put the HTMl code also or make a fiddle

Comment: just made up the jsfiddle above

Comment: so does anything work by now ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415065/css-overflow-firefox-issue?rq=1

Comment: @DeppG hmm, it's quite a different case.. :|

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/VKPku/4/

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya the `.scroller-container` really needs to be on the both side

Comment: @SamuelAdam: Sorry, I'm not clear what do you mean. If you could show what you need result by image, I can help you.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya image added :)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/VKPku/5/

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya it's just like I mentioned on my question, I need to add float to carousel-inner means a static width needed (px), which I really try to avoid here..